# How do I use collect keep in parse, to get embedded blocks?

Tags: parsing, red

Looking at the html example here: http://www.red-lang.org/2013/11/041-introducing-parse.html

I would like to parse the following:

```
"val1-12*more text-something"
```

Where:

- `"-"` marks values which should be in the same block, and
- `"*"` should start a new block.

So, I want this:

```
[ ["val1" "12"] ["more text" "something"] ]
```

and at the moment I get this:

```
red>> data: "val1-12*more text-something"
== "val1-12*more text-something"

red>> c: charset reduce ['not #"-" #"*"]
== make bitset! [not #{000000000024}]

red>> parse data [collect [any [keep any c [#"-" | #"*" | end ]]]]
== ["val1" "12" "more text" "something"]
```

(I actually tried some other permutations, which didn't get me any farther.)

So, what's missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work by nesting COLLECT.  For e.g.

```
keep-pair: [
    keep some c 
    #"-"
    keep some c 
] 

parse data [
    collect [
        some [
            collect [keep-pair]
            #"*"
            collect [keep-pair]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Using your example input this outputs the result you wanted:

```
[["val1" "12"] ["more text" "something"]]
```

However I got funny feeling you maybe wanted the parse rule to be more flexible than the example input provided?

Comment: Good answer. You improve it by creating an external rule for the inner COLLECT to avoid repeating it.

Comment: @DocKimbel - Agree.  My initial update was going to be with a `collect-pair: []` external rule (with COLLECT in so more DRY).  However I preferred above which keeps COLLECT clearly visible in the main PARSE rule.

Comment: @draegtun do you need to have the reference to keep-pair in a block? Can you do `collect keep-pair`?

Comment: @rgchris Unfortunately it doesn't work without the block (no error just get `[[]]` back, which in itself is odd, ie. why not `[[][]]`?).